# Windows 10 Creator Update Version 1703

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-v1703

is it possible to download **creator update version 1703**  *iso file* and install it without ***windows update assistant app***? if that so what steps should i follow after downloaded the iso file?

I do not need to know where to download **iso file**, i just need know how to proceed the installation process after download it.

Comment: use rufus and create an bootable USB drive or mount the iso and run setup.exe to upgrade

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can download it without problems as long as you run the download on an activated Windows 10 installation. Also, it will have to be the same edition of Windows 10 as the computer uses.

Now as it proves to be a bit difficult to find the links manually, personally, I like to use [Jan Krohn's Microsoft Windows and Office ISO Download Tool](https://www.heidoc.net/joomla/technology-science/microsoft/67-microsoft-windows-and-office-iso-download-tool?showall=&limitstart=) for downloading the ISO. After successfully downloading the ISO, you can burn it to a DVD or use something like [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) to create a bootable USB pendrive with the ISO on it.

Comment: We always appreciate the contributions from our Super User community members, but both the questions author **and** the person providing an answer should try to ensure that this query isn't a duplicate of a previous question.  In this particular case, it has been asked many times before.

Comment: @Run5k I'm sorry - I was very tired and did not think about checking (this, of course, cannot be an excuse, only an explanation). Added my answer there, too - I would like to delete that one, but unfortunately, one cannot delete accepted answers.

Comment: should i delete this?

Comment: well with the help of flolilolio, i have already installed the creator update so this question is no longer need any answers